# SyntaxError - expected an indented block

Tags: python, syntax-error, indentation

when i run this i get "SyntaxError - expected an indented block" popup. I have no idea how to fix it and I need help.

```
solved_places ={
"a1": False, "a2": False, "a3": False, "a4": False, "a5": False, "a6": False, "a7": False, "a8": False, "a9": False, "a10": False,
"b1": False, "b2": False, "b3": False, "b4": False, "b5": False, "b6": False, "b7": False, "b8": False, "b9": False, "b10": False,
"c1": False, "c2": False, "c3": False, "c4": False, "c5": False, "c6": False, "c7": False, "c8": False, "c9": False, "c10": False,
"d1": False, "d2": False, "d3": False, "d4": False, "d5": False, "d6": False, "d7": False, "d8": False, "d9": False, "d10": False,
"e1": False, "e2": False, "e3": False, "e4": False, "e5": False, "e6": False, "e7": False, "e8": False, "e9": False, "e10": False,
"f1": False, "f2": False, "f3": False, "f4": False, "f5": False, "f6": False, "f7": False, "f8": False, "f9": False, "f10": False,
"g1": False, "g2": False, "g3": False, "g4": False, "g5": False, "g6": False, "g7": False, "g8": False, "g9": False, "g10": False,
"h1": False, "h2": False, "h3": False, "h4": False, "h5": False, "h6": False, "h7": False, "h8": False, "h9": False, "h10": False,
"i1": False, "i2": False, "i3": False, "i4": False, "i5": False, "i6": False, "i7": False, "i8": False, "i9": False, "i10": False,
"j1": False, "j2": False, "j3": False, "j4": False, "j5": False, "j6": False, "j7": False, "j8": False, "j9": False, "j10": False,
            }
```

Comment: No repro. The code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is only a fraction of your code, so I'd say if you can't find the issue you might have tabs and spaces mixed up. Try using your editor to replace all tabs with 4 spaces (Python's standard) and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

At the end you have a comma after the last item and some indents after that, that will probably be the problem

Comment: You can add commas at the end of the last element in lists or dictionaries and no error or warning will be displayed, so I doubt it is that

Comment: Oh i thought it might be that I have never done it so I thought it might cause an error